# Android 12 splash screen conditional start screen

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, splash-screen

I went through the [documentation on the splash screen for Android 12](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen) and also on [migrating existing splash screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate) but it doesn't mention clearly how to select the start screen based on the condition.

Specifically, I had added the check if the user is signed in like this previously:

```
class SplashScreenActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        if(viewModel.isUserSignedIn()) {
            navigateToMain()
        } else {
            navigateToAuth()
        }
    }
}
```

where the `SplashScreenActivity` was marked as the default launch activity. When I keep it like this, Android studio gives a warning - `The application should not provide its own launch screen`.

I modified it as per the guide and removed `setContentView` from the activity and called `installSplashScreen`.

```
class SplashScreenActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen()

        if(viewModel.isUserSignedIn()) {
            navigateToMain()
        } else {
            navigateToAuth()
        }
    }
}
```

When I run on the emulator, it seems to be working as expected but the Android Studio continues to give the same warning.

Is this the right way to migrate to the Android 12 splash screen, if yes, why is the error on Android Studio still showing?
Also, do we need to keep the activity as the default launcher or is there a change required there?

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Comment: I believe this is a bug and decided to just keep it as it is. The warning stays but it works fine on all devices.

Comment: Any update or solution for this ?

Comment: @KhushbuShah I don't think there is a solution. I believe this is created thinking the single activity application in mind. For my new applications, I only have MainActivity and using the navigation component to navigate between fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to call `setContentView` here.
So the code would look like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    installSplashScreen()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

    if(viewModel.isUserSignedIn()) {
        navigateToMain()
    } else {
        navigateToAuth()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well. It doesn't show splash screen on older devices and the android studio continues to give the same warning.

Comment: what's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 26

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're creating an activity just for the SplashScreen. In the documentation, they state that the SplashScreen should be called in MainActivity [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate)

Basically, you either need to set your splashScreen in the MainActivity or do this after migrating:

> After you've migrated to the new splash screen experience for Android 12 and higher, your custom splash screen Activity is still
> left over, so you’ll need to choose what to do with it. You have the
> following options:
>
> - Keep the custom activity, but prevent it from displaying
> - Keep the custom activity for branding reasons
> - Remove the custom activity, and adapt your app as needed

Comment: What you are suggesting is that I need to rename the activity to `MainActivity.kt` and keep everything else the same. This defeats the purpose of having an activity to navigate to correct activity.

Comment: No, I am suggesting you follow the documentation and migrate your splashScreen to the mainActivity not rename your SplashcreenActivity.kt  file, meaning, you will not use it but use the MainActivity you have. Also, using more than one activity is bad practice.

Comment: But as you see the initial activity depends on whether the user is signed in or not. How would I achieve that?